# Page loads in browser but google page speed and GT Metrix both say they timeout.

Tags: https, server, pagespeed

I have a [website](https://www.xplorocity.ca) that loads fine in a browser, but when i put it in GTMetrix or Google page speed they both timeout. GTMetrix says one problem could be with my SSL certificate, but both Chrome and Firefox say it is a secure connection.

Not sure what to do?